# Parse class info from source file

Tags: c++, class

So, after 2 days of debugging why some classes in code weren't initializing properly, and finding out, that was because same class, from same header, had two different members in different compile units (because of some macro bullshiterry), I decided to somehow recheck all codebase to know if there could be another error of this sort behind the corner.

At lest in my head, the way to do it was simple:

1. generate compilation database of all .cpp files in the project
2. using this compilation database generate preprocessor output for each .cpp file (this is more or less eliminates differences in compilers, and we would not need additional info on the next step)
3. go through each file dumping usefull information about each class in those files (like alignment, members and their types. ets)
4. if some classes already were parsed by us from previous files - compare them, and in case of any significant differences - print an error

First two steps are more or less easy, but I haven't found any tool which would alow me to do 3rd step.

Is there such tool, which can parse c++ classes into easily processable json or xml?
(or maybe you even know existing tool which can check codebase for such errors automatically, this also will be helpful)

Comment: clang's AST could be used

Comment: "Understand" from scitools will be your friend